# coverflow images onclick streaming specific sound file (mp3)

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, coverflow, soundplayer

i googled coverflow code i found one useful and work great to me (im not professional in android development ), what i need it.
when click on each image it will stream predetermined mp3 song for each image and another click will stop it ,
so each image will have different mp3 song which all mp3 songs stored in app it self .

```
public class CoverFlowExample extends Activity { 

/** Called when the activity is first created. */ 

@Override 

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

CoverFlow coverFlow; 

coverFlow = new CoverFlow(this); 

coverFlow.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this)); 

ImageAdapter coverImageAdapter =  new ImageAdapter(this); 

//coverImageAdapter.createReflectedImages(); 

coverFlow.setAdapter(coverImageAdapter); 

coverFlow.setSpacing(-25); 

coverFlow.setSelection(4, true); 

coverFlow.setAnimationDuration(1000); 

setContentView(coverFlow); 

    } 

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter { 

int mGalleryItemBackground; 

private Context mContext; 

private FileInputStream fis; 

private Integer[] mImageIds = { 

R.drawable.aa, 

R.drawable.aab, 

R.drawable.aabb, 

R.drawable.aabbb, 

R.drawable.aac, 


}; 

private ImageView[] mImages; 

public ImageAdapter(Context c) { 

mContext = c; 

mImages = new ImageView[mImageIds.length]; 

  } 

public boolean createReflectedImages() { 

 //The gap we want between the reflection and the original image 

final int reflectionGap = 4; 

int index = 0; 

for (int imageId : mImageIds) { 

Bitmap originalImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),  

imageId); 

 int width = originalImage.getWidth(); 

 int height = originalImage.getHeight(); 

   //This will not scale but will flip on the Y axis 

 Matrix matrix = new Matrix(); 

 matrix.preScale(1, -1); 

   //Create a Bitmap with the flip matrix applied to it. 

    //We only want the bottom half of the image 

Bitmap reflectionImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalImage, 0, height/2, 
width, height/2, matrix, false); 

//Create a new bitmap with same width but taller to fit reflection 

Bitmap bitmapWithReflection = Bitmap.createBitmap(width  

 , (height + height/2), Config.ARGB_8888); 

 //Create a new Canvas with the bitmap that's big enough for 

 //the image plus gap plus reflection 

 Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapWithReflection); 

//Draw in the original image 

canvas.drawBitmap(originalImage, 0, 0, null); 

//Draw in the gap 

 Paint deafaultPaint = new Paint(); 

 canvas.drawRect(0, height, width, height + reflectionGap, deafaultPaint); 

//Draw in the reflection 

 canvas.drawBitmap(reflectionImage,0, height + reflectionGap, null); 

//Create a shader that is a linear gradient that covers the reflection 

 Paint paint = new Paint();  

LinearGradient shader = new LinearGradient(0, originalImage.getHeight(), 0,  

bitmapWithReflection.getHeight() + reflectionGap, 0x70ffffff, 0x00ffffff,  

TileMode.CLAMP);  

//Set the paint to use this shader (linear gradient) 

 paint.setShader(shader);  

//Set the Transfer mode to be porter duff and destination in 

paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_IN));  

//Draw a rectangle using the paint with our linear gradient 

 canvas.drawRect(0, height, width,  

bitmapWithReflection.getHeight() + reflectionGap, paint);  

 ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext); 

imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapWithReflection); 

imageView.setLayoutParams(new CoverFlow.LayoutParams(120, 180)); 

imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

 mImages[index++] = imageView;           
 }       
 return true;   
 } 
 public int getCount() { 

 return mImageIds.length;     
     }    
  public Object getItem(int position) { 

 return position;      
  }     
 public long getItemId(int position) { 

  return position;     
   }     
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 

      //Use this code if you want to load from resources 

 ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext); 

 i.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]); 

 i.setLayoutParams(new CoverFlow.LayoutParams(430, 430)); 

 i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);                    

BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) i.getDrawable(); 

 drawable.setAntiAlias(true); 

 return i; 

 //return mImages[position]; 

         } 

  /** Returns the size (0.0f to 1.0f) of the views  

   * depending on the 'offset' to the center. */  

  public float getScale(boolean focused, int offset) {  

  /* Formula: 1 / (2 ^ offset) */  

 return Math.max(0, 1.0f / (float)Math.pow(2, Math.abs(offset)));  

           }   

       } 
     }
```